# TOR от имени определенной страны

Tags: windows, proxy, tor

Методом тыка выяснил, что некоторые требующиеся для работы научные/учебные сайты в России не пускают запросы из страны, где я сейчас нахожусь (как и из ряда других). Решил, что наиболее простым способом будет настройка TOR как прокси с указанием выходного российского узла.

Сделал новый torrc, записал в него

```
SocksPort  №№№№№
ExitNodes  {ru} 
StrictNodes  1
```

но при запуске `tor.exe -f torrc` получаю сообщение "Starting with guard context "default"", и выходной узел оказывается в какой-нибудь западной Европе или США с понятным результатом.

Не подскажете, что я делаю неверно, и как мне заставить работать TOR так, как мне нужно?